# Find all forms of a verb, given one form of the verb

Tags: verbos

Is there any software that I can use to find all forms of a Spanish verb, given one form of the verb? I know of an online tool called [Whitaker's Words](http://archives.nd.edu/words.html) that does this for Latin verbs, but I haven't yet found an equivalent tool for Spanish verbs.

Comment: You could try SpanishDict for a fun simple way of seeing verb conjugations.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the [RAE dictionary](http://www.rae.es/) finds any simple tense of any verb. Example: you write *durmiéramos* as the word to find, and it redirects you to the definition of *dormir*. From there you can click on the **Conjugar** button and you have every conjugation of that verb.

Note that this does not work if you write complex forms such as *hubiéramos dormido*. Instead, search for *hubiéramos* and you have the definition of *haber* and access to its conjugation.

Comment: Whitaker's Words, has a problem most softwares for Spanish could also have: when it does not know an irregular conjugation, it just fills the blanks, accepting and producing non-existent forms. The difference with RAE's conjugation tool is that it is curated by the very authors of the single most important Spanish dictionary. I personally think you do not need to try a more or less known software provided there is something like this (of which, BTW, I have heard no negative comments so far). Regarding composite tenses, they are a no-brainer once you know simple forms and auxiliary verbs.

Answer (score 2):

There actually is one website that I know of that can do this - see here: http://www.123teachme.com/spanish_verb_conjugation/despedir

Answer (score 1):

[This website](http://www.onoma.es/) is an automatic conjugator for Spanish verbs. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As there are several similar websites for Spanish verbs conjugation, I'll try to make a list (included those already mentioned in the answers):

- [wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ESverbs.aspx?v=conjugar)
- [123teachme.com](http://www.123teachme.com/spanish_verb_conjugation/conjugar)
- [onoma.es](http://www.onoma.es/)
- [reverso.net](http://conjugador.reverso.net/conjugacion-espanol-verbo-conjugar.html)
- [conjugacion.es](http://www.conjugacion.es/del/verbo/conjugar.php)